# WiX Show Dialog Based on Feature to be Installed

Tags: wix, conditional-statements

Let me be upfront I am novice with WiX. I have a custom dialog CustomSetupTypeDlg.wxs that changes the Typical/Custom/Complete to Desktop/Server/Suite.  It sets  WixUI_InstallMode to InstallDesktop, InstallServer and InstallSuite appropriately.

I need to have the user browse for an installation folder depending upon what feature is to be installed.  If InstallDesktop or InstallSuite is selected the user has to select two different paths for DESKTOPINSTALLDIRECTORY and SERVERINSTALLDIRECTORY.  However if the install mode is InstallServer only SERVERINSTALLDIRECTORY choice should be presented.

I am uncertain on how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to simplify the project by splitting the desktop and server features into two separate installers.

Answer (score 0):

You want to have actions in your InstallExecute sequence that display the dialogs you need.  Inside the tag you provide a conditional, which, when true, causes the action to actually happen.  See this [tutorial](http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/lesson5.php#expression), specifically section 5.3 for a list of conditionals.

Comment: I do a little better scavenging existing code.  Can you point me to snippet with this is in use?